# How to encode ".." for use in a URL path?

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I'm trying to construct a URL with something like:

```
var myUrl = '/path/to/api/' + encodeURIComponent(str);
```

But if `str` is `..` then your browser automatically lops off a path segment so that the URL becomes `/path/to` which is not what I want.

I've tried encoding `..` as `%2E%2E` but your browser still re-interprets it before the request is sent. Is there anything I can do to have path *actually* come through to my server as `/path/to/api/..`?

Comment: that seems really fragile - can you change the server?

Comment: '../' is how you backup a directory. So it is being interpreted as you wrote it. Why do you need `..` at the end of your file path? You might be better served to change the name if you don't want it to back up to `/path/to`

Comment: @DanielA.White It's *not* a problem with the server. The browser automatically changes the URL before it even hits my server. That's the problem.

Comment: @amflare I won't be using `..` in practice, I just want to support arbitrary strings without your browser doing something stupid with it.

Comment: @mpen i mean your server should change not to accept that.

Comment: @DanielA.White The server will sanitize it into something else. That code is already in-place.

Comment: Browsers don't magically remove `..` from JS strings. Are you using a link or something? Show that

Comment: @Oriol Not from the string, from the request. Go ahead and try it, paste this in your address bar: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947065/..` and then try `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947065/%2E%2E` -- same thing.

Comment: @mpen can you give us an example with an actual string rather than linux commands? What kind of arbitrary string are you talking about?

Comment: @amflare I think he's pretty clear: he wants to take an arbitrary user-provided string and send it to the server as part of a URL, but the browser is rewriting certain forms if they're in the path.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I get that, but I don't understand the insistence of using `..` in all his examples. His code should work fine if you used something like `'test'`. So clearly there is another layer here. Perhaps it's obvious and I'm just missing it.

Comment: @amflare That's right, it works for everything *except* `..` and `.` but I'm a stickler and want it to work for 100% of inputs.

Comment: I'm afraid you are out of luck then. The answer below is correct. `.` and `..` are reserved for relative path navigation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is not supported because the behaviour would violate [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.3).

From [Section 2.3.  Unreserved Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3) (emphasis mine):

> Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
> purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase
> letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.
>
> ```
>  unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> ```
>
> URIs that differ in the replacement of an unreserved character with
> its corresponding percent-encoded US-ASCII octet are equivalent: they
> identify the same resource.  However, URI comparison implementations
> do not always perform normalization prior to comparison (see Section
> 6).  **For consistency, percent-encoded octets in the ranges** of ALPHA
> (%41-%5A and %61-%7A), DIGIT (%30-%39), hyphen (%2D), **period (%2E)**,
> underscore (%5F), or tilde (%7E) **should not be created by URI
> producers and, when found in a URI, should be decoded to their
> corresponding unreserved characters by URI normalizers**.

From [Section 6.2.2.3.  Path Segment Normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.3) (emphasis mine):

> **The complete path segments "." and ".." are intended only for use
> within relative references (Section 4.1) and are removed as part of
> the reference resolution process** (Section 5.2).  However, some
> deployed implementations incorrectly assume that reference resolution
> is not necessary when the reference is already a URI and thus fail to
> remove dot-segments when they occur in non-relative paths.  URI
> normalizers should remove dot-segments by applying the
> remove_dot_segments algorithm to the path, as described in
> [Section 5.2.4.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4)):

Comment: Well that's dumb. I should be able to have anything I want in the path without it being re-interpreted as something else. This is a tie over from the olden days when paths reflected files on disk but that's no longer true. Anyway, thank you. Looks like I'm SOL

Comment: @mpen the browser doesn't know if the resource is backed by disk or something else.

Comment: @DanielA.White Exactly, so it shouldn't make any assumptions. Just send the request on through and I'll deal with it on the other end.

Comment: @mpen that would be a huge breaking change.

Comment: I'm not sure it *should* be breaking in theory, since a compliant server should already be performing the same transformation. In practice... yeah, it would probably break a lot.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not saying we should change it now, it's probably too late for that. Just unfortunate is all :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've actually done similar by double encoding the text, then un-encoding it on the server back end. However, mine were query parameters, not part of the path.

PS. This is written on my phone, I'll add an example later.

Comment: You mean encoding `..` as `%252E%252E`? I can run it through one decoding on the server, but two is weird and would cause problems.

Comment: Yes, and your correct it's weird. It was a hack to get around system limitations we weren't allowed to change.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as there's [no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35947190/65387), there's not much we can do but error:

```
export function encodeUriComponent(str) {
    if(str === '.' || str === '..') {
        throw new Error(`Cannot URI-encode "${str}" per RFC 3986 §6.2.2.3`)
    }
    return encodeURIComponent(str);
}
```

I feel that this is a better option than arbitrarily modifying the URL path which is exactly what I was trying to avoid by using `encodeURIComponent`.